# Is there a way to stop the images show on top of the opacity overlay?

Tags: overlay, z-index, opacity, sidebar

I'm new to HTML/CSS. I created this sidebar that when clicked, it will slide from the left side, and while it slides, an opacity background will show. Unfortunately, the images show on top of the opacity overlay and I can't find the problem to make it stop showing on top of the opacity so brightly. I'm doing this for a project asked by our subject teacher.

[image]

I've already tried using z-index but I'm not really an expert here since I'm a beginner and I get help from websites like w3schools.com

```
 <style>
    body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

.header {
  background-color: #fffff;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px 14px;
  background-color: #72cef6;
  z-index: 90;
}

}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ccebff;
  color: #666666 
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ff9966;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #99d6ff;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="Moderator's Profile.html">Modertor's Page</a> 
  <a href="#">Members and Officers</a> 
  <a href="Constitution and By Laws.html">Constitution and By Laws</a> 
  <a href="#">Activity Layout</a>
  <a href="about.html">Info.</a> 
</div>

<span style="font-size:18px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><font 

color="#72cef6">___</font><img src="menu.png" height="24"></span>


<style>
element.style {
    display: block;
}

.mm-open .mm-fullscreen-bg {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div class="mm-fullscreen-bg" style="display: block;"></div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width 
="250px";document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
"rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";object.style.zIndex="999";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = 
"0";document.body.style.backgroundColor 

= "white";
}
</script>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

I just want to achieve the results of [this.](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Fimages%2FResponsive-Multi-purpose-Navigation-Plugin-jQuery-Pushy.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Ftags.php%3F%2Foverlay%2520menu%2F&docid=Ra20IJeGib_utM&tbnid=w2prl9LumW_ifM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwipsbPDtrrfAhXPZt4KHQ7yDHYQMwg-KAAwAA..i&w=414&h=306&bih=734&biw=792&q=sidenav%20overlay%20with%20opacity&ved=0ahUKEwipsbPDtrrfAhXPZt4KHQ7yDHYQMwg-KAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8).

Oh, and don't mind the links provided on the sidenav.

Comment: It would really help your code readability if you loved all your CSS to the head. Having it online just makes it difficult to see the structure of your page. You also have multiple opening body tags and close your head twice. Run your code through an html validator and fix all the errors it gives. Just search for "html beautifier". Please update your example after that.

Comment: thanks, I'll definitely try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your using this example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav)

So you can achieve this give your ***img*** tag an ***id*** let say ***some-image***

`<img id='some-image' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">`

than add this to openNav();

```
document.getElementById('some-image').style.opacity = "0.2";
```

When your closing you can revert back to white on **closeNav()**

```
document.getElementById('some-image').style.opacity = "1";
```

I created jsfiddle example for you please check

https://jsfiddle.net/whatatimetobealive/4wack0y1/11/

If you provide all your code I can help you on that too but currently **body** section is missing so its hard to assume what exactly do you have there.

Hope it helps...

Comment: this actually helped! i can't tell you how much frustration caused me. thank you so much! T.T

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work, take the part of the benefit into DIV and reduce the opacity